# Error de no "se puede convertir un String a system.io.stream"

Tags: c#, consola

Estoy tratando de crear un txt a través de una aplicación de consola, utilice el código que encontré en la pagina de microsoft pero al agregarlo y agregar la librería me aparece el erro que se ve en la imagen, 
[image: error system.io.stream]

---

si, lo siento la fuente es la siguiente

[Cómo leer y escribir en un archivo de texto mediante Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/es-co/help/816149/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-a-text-file-by-using-visual-c)

Comment: Proba agregarle un @ al inicio del string ej: @"PATH"

Comment: en que pagina encontraste el codigo? si lo mencionas una fuente estaria bueno que pongas el link

Comment: en que contexto esta el codigo? porque la imagen esta cortada en la parte superior y no se visualiza si esta en alguna incluido en algun metodos

Comment: Estas utilizando el `StreamWriter` del namespace `System.IO`? Me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Por favor mira [ask]. La seccion de respuestas es solo para dejar respuestas. Si tenes una edicion, podes hacerla apretando el boton [edit]. El codigo siempre debe ir como texto, asi como el error completo

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes una cadena de texto:

para esto solo necesitas las librerias de sistema
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

//en la clase principal agregas:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            string test = "esto es un texto";

            // convertir string to stream
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( test );
                //stream es la salida
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray ); 



            //ahora si tienes un stream a string 
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream );
            string texto = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine( texto );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

saludos